# How to install a Jupyter Lab extension which is not published

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, blockly

I would like to **install** the following Jupyter Lab Extension https://github.com/deathbeds/jupyterlab-outsource

The installation guidelines of the `README` file do not work. So I tried the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/deathbeds/jupyterlab-outsource.git
cd jupyterlab-outsource
jupyter labextension install src/_core
jupyter labextension install src/blockly
jupyter labextension install src/prosemirror
```

The output of the `jupyter labextension list` command shows that those **extensions are enabled**.

However, when launching `jupyter lab` I get the following warning messages in the jupyter notebook log:

```
Failed to fetch package metadata for '@deathbeds/jupyterlab-outsource-prosemirror': <HTTPError 404: 'Not Found'>
Failed to fetch package metadata for '@deathbeds/jupyterlab-outsource': <HTTPError 404: 'Not Found'>
Failed to fetch package metadata for '@deathbeds/jupyterlab-outsource-blockly': <HTTPError 404: 'Not Found'>
```

Could you please explain how to get the extensions work?

Answer (score 0):

The warning messages you posted allude to several items that are listed as commented out [here](https://github.com/deathbeds/jupyterlab-outsource#installation) on that page you reference for the extension, specifically https://github.com/deathbeds/jupyterlab-outsource. Did you try running that code to see if it fixes it?

```
jupyter labextension install \
@deathbeds/jupyterlab-outsource
@deathbeds/jupyterlab-outsource-prosemirror \
@deathbeds/jupyterlab-outsource-blockly
```

I do note that the last commit there says "start updating to jlab 1.0" in several places. Maybe it has not have kept up with the many advances in JupyterLab recently?

Comment: _I do note that the last commit there says "start updating to jlab 1.0" in several places. Maybe it has not have kept up with the many advances in JupyterLab recently?_ To add onto that, this appears to be a small, 1-person project, so these kinds of issues are to be expected.

Comment: The result of that command is ValueError: "@deathbeds/jupyterlab-outsource" is not a valid npm package. Infact this extension cannot be found from the search bar of the Jupyter Lab extensions.

Comment: My jupyter lab version is 1.2.6